# Print date from timestamp value

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

i have a table in mysql db ( created_date). It stores timestamps (INT value).
I would like to print the column values in sql, what function to use for that. For he format, everything suits me.

```
Select WHAT_FUNCTION_TO_USE( created_date) from users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_date`) FROM `users`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format the date the see this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Like this:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219);
        -> '2007-11-30 10:30:19'
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219) + 0;
        -> 20071130103019.000000
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),
    ->                      '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x');
        -> '2007 30th November 10:30:59 2007'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'%d-%m-%Y ); // dd-mm-yyyy format
```

or

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'%m-%d-%Y ); // mm-dd-yyyy format
```